# How to change spring profiles in Junit testing

Tags: java, xml, spring, junit, spring-profiles

I have used @Activeprofiles along with importing the spring profile containing .xml to context configuration but it does not seem to load the profile to the respective Junit class. below is the snippet of what I have done. The assert compare value is not been changed as per the profile that is set. Any tips to improve on to get the spring profile activated.
TEST CLASS.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("unittest-hsql")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:spring/Services.xml"
    "classpath:spring/profiles/dev.xml"
})

public class TestSpringProfile
{
 @Test
    public void testGetCronExpression()
    {
        String expression = EventLimitation.getExpression();
        assertThat(expression, is("20"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify in the **beans** tag of your profile-specific configuration, the **profile** attribute:

```
<!--language:xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans profile="dev">
...
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work as long as you have in the file spring/profiles/dev.xml something like the below where you specify a profile named "unittest-hsql":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <beans profile="unittest-hsql">
        <bean id="applicationPropertiesPlaceholder"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:profiles/hsqldb.profile.properties</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

</beans>
```